# Tuple aggregate construction which infers types and elides move/copy constructor calls?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, tuples, aggregate

Consider the following `mypair` class (I'm not sure if this is the best way to do things, but it seems to work):

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  A() {}
  A(const A&) { std::cout << "Copy" << std::endl; }
  A(A&&) { std::cout << "Move" << std::endl; }
  std::string s;
};

template <class T0, class T1>
struct mypair
{
  T0 x0;
  T1 x1;
};

template <class T0, class T1, int N = -1>
struct get_class {};

template<class T0, class T1>
struct get_class<T0, T1, 0>
{
  static T0& get_func(mypair<T0, T1>& x) { return x.x0; }
  static const T0& get_func(const mypair<T0, T1>& x) { return x.x0; }
  static T0&& get_func(mypair<T0, T1>&& x) { return std::move(x.x0); }
};

template<class T0, class T1>
struct get_class<T0, T1, 1>
{
  static T1& get_func(mypair<T0, T1>& x) { return x.x1; }
  static const T1& get_func(const mypair<T0, T1>& x) { return x.x1; }
  static T1&& get_func(mypair<T0, T1>&& x) { return std::move(x.x1); }
};

template <int N, class T0, class T1>
auto get(mypair<T0, T1>& x) -> decltype(get_class<T0,T1,N>::get_func(x)) 
{ return get_class<T0,T1,N>::get_func(x); }

#define MAKE_PAIR(x1, x2) mypair<decltype(x1), decltype(x2)>{x1, x2}

int main()
{
  auto x = MAKE_PAIR(A(), A());
  get<0>(x);
  get<1>(x);
}
```

[(ideone link)](http://ideone.com/hBwpU)

The answer [when is aggregate initialization valid in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273437/when-is-aggregate-initialisation-valid-in-c0x/6273662#6273662) says we can elide copies/moves by doing aggregate initialization.

Hence, we can construct `mypair`s using `MAKE_PAIR` without the need to perform any moves or copies.

I would like to generalize `MAKE_PAIR` to `MAKE_TUPLE`, i.e. take any number of arguments.

Requirements are (as with `MAKE_PAIR`):

> (1) Types are inferred.
>   (2) Moves/copies are elided when constructing from temporaries (i.e. construction happens in place).

Existing library solutions (e.g. Boost) will be fine, though I'd prefer something which accepts rvalue references. Or just code here is great also, or a mix of the two.

If it is at all possible, I'd like it if it optimized out empty members whilst still eliding moves/copy constructor calls, but I have a feeling that is asking too much.

Comment: You can't _elide_ copy/move in a tuple in the same way that an aggregate is initialized, if that's what you're thinking. (If you really want an aggregate, then make one.) The next best thing is that `std::make_tuple` uses the best possible constructor, which really shouldn't hurt at all. You pay for the fancy structure that tuples provide by them not being aggregates. I'm not sure why you're so worried about this extra step, almost surely you will have far greater performance bottlenecks elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is already such a feature in the C++0x Standard Library- a `std::make_tuple`. Even if you get bored, you can make your own.

```
template<typename... T> std::tuple<T...> make_tuple(T...&& refs) {
    return std::tuple<T...> { std::forward<T>(refs)... };
}
```

Comment: I believe std::make_tuple calls move constructors instead of constructing elements in place. Can you show me code on any compiler where std::make_tuple(A()) doesn't print "Move"? MAKE_PAIR doesn't print "Move", it skips elides the call to the move constructor.

Comment: `std::make_tuple` uses `std::decay`.

Comment: The official make_tuple also performs some special type transformation for reference_wrappers. `make_tuple(ref(some_int))` actually yields a `tuple<int&>`-object.

Answer (score 1):

`make_tuple` is declared `make_tuple(Args&&...)` so `make_tuple(A{foo},B{blah})` can and (depending on your compiler's calling conventions) almost certainly will elide the moves if you give it temporary arguments in construction as above.

You cannot generalise `make_tuple` to force a construct in-place. Here's a counter-example

```
struct A {
   A (int);
};

struct B {
   B (int, int);
};
```

If I tried to write `my_make_tuple` which would construct a `tuple<A,B>` by constructing in-place it would have to work out that `my_make_tuple(1,2,3)` is value-equivalent to `make_tupe(A{1},B{2,3})`

It should be immediately obvious that `my_make_tuple(1,2,3)` would have to be value-equivalent to `make_tupe(B{1,2},A{3})`

Whereas the constructors of A and B could be ambiguously overloaded, and given that C++ has no reflection, it is obvious to me that what you are asking for is impossible in the general case.

`make_tuple` only works becase the input types are clearly separated in the argument list. You shouldn't worry about the cost of move operators, for all reasonable cases they are incredibly cheap. Also, they can be elided.

If performance is critical, inline the constructors and let the compiler figure it out.