# Automatic constructor generation in C++?

Tags: c++, class, struct, constructor, code-generation

imagine I have

```
struct Foo
{
   int a;
   string s;
   float f;
}
```

So now when I need to create new Foo I need to add a constructor:

```
struct Foo
    {
       int a;
       string s;
       float f;
       Foo(int a, string s, float f)
       {
          this->a = a;
          this->s = s;
          this->f = f;
       }
    }
```

However this method of manually writing constructors is really time consuming, especially with structs/classes with 10+ properties. My questions is: Is there a way to automatically generate such constructors?

Comment: IDE code autogeneration? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern ? Procedural code generation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273437/when-is-aggregate-initialisation-valid-in-c11 (i.e. aggregate initalization) ? Reflection library? ... I sense an anti-pattern in what you're trying to do there, BTW.

Comment: `So now when I need to create new Foo I need to add a constructor` No, you don't. Leave it without one and use _aggregate initialisation_.

Comment: This is called "aggregate initialization". Go to Google, and look it up. You will need a compiler that supports the current C++ standard.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well, the `thing = {other, things}` syntax was always valid for C compatibility, right? Only the `thing{uniform, initialisation}` one was new in C++11.

Comment: Also, as Humam pointed out, assigning in the body what can be initialised in the initialisation-list is a huge _nope_. There are so many reasons that the former won't work for particular types/qualifications of member... and even where it would work, it's inefficient (causes your members to be default-initialised and then assigned) and sloppy style.

Answer (score 9):

```
struct Foo
{
  int a;
  std::string s;
  float f;
};

Foo f{42,"Foo",0.0};
```

works just fine, but a constructor gives you more control e.g. check of init value.

Answer (score 5):

First if you want to write the constructor by yourself it is better to do it like this:

```
struct Foo
{
   int a;
   string s;
   float f;
   Foo()=default;// this is needed if Foo needs to be default constructable (Thanks to @ NathanOliver)
   Foo(int a, string s, float f):a(a),s(s),f(f){
   }
};
```

If you do not want to do it manually (the manual option is definitely better and more controllable), you may use this:

```
struct Foo
{
  int a;
  std::string s;
  float f;
  //The default constructor is exist by default here
};
Foo obj{0,"",0.0f};
```

Comment: May want to note that unlike the first case the second case is also default constructable.

Comment: Good point: assigning in the body what can be initialised in the initialisation-list is a huge _nope_.

Comment: You probably want to add an in-class-initializer for `a` and `f` for the explicitly-defaulted ctor to pick up. Maybe also for the aggregate-init-example (>=C++14), though that depends.

Answer (score 1):

If your structs are PODs, you can use {} to initialize them.

```
struct A {
  int a;
  int b;
} foo = {2,3};
```

In more modern C++, the restrictions for this syntax have been relaxed. It's called [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

Comment: To clarify, the `thing = {other, things}` syntax was always valid for C compatibility, and only the `thing{uniform, initialisation}` one was new in C++11.

Comment: Not PODS, but *aggregates*.

Answer (score 1):

While I personally would recommend, using a constructor, as the constructor has the advantage of checking it's type parameters, for errors, there is a method for initializing data members, introduced in `C++11`, called `list-initialization`, that uses a list written by the user that automatically assigns data members consecutively. Here is an example for a sample struct `foo`

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
int main()
{
    Foo bar {27,86}; // Note the use of curly braces here to initialize the list. There is
                     // no range or error checking, but a and b are consecutively initialized
    return 0;
}
```

If you didn't read my comment in the code, here it is:
***Note the use of curly braces here to initialize the list. There is no range or error checking, but a and b are consecutively initialized***

### What if my compiler doesn't support C++11?

If a compiler doesn't support C++11, `Uniform Initialization`, a feature that has always been in C++, would come in handy for you. An example below for the same struct Foo:

```
Foo baz = {22,33}; //Note the '=' sign here, that separates it from list-initialization.
```